I need to acsess data in an XML via looping over the elements
I have a xml file and need to accsess a specific part.
I get close to it with:
from lxml import objectify
path = xml_path
xml = objectify.parse(open(path))
root = xml.getroot()

# Access the list of 'Evt' elements in 'History'
events = root.getchildren()[1].History.getchildren()  

However the structure look like the following
   -History
    |-Env
    |   |-EnvD
    |        |-Data
    |        |-Data
    |-Env
        |-EnvD
             |-Data
             |-Data

So I need to loop over each Env,EnVD, ... to reach the data.
Using something like
events = root.getchildren()[1].History.getchildren()
for event in events:
    Data_elements = event.findall('.//Data')  

does not work as it finds the elements, however without the internal elements. I would need to use
events = root.getchildren()[1].History.Env.EnvD.Data.getchildren()

to get to the elements while looping over Env and EnvD.
Any ideas? Thanks a lot

What does this have to do with [tag:dataframe] and [tag:schema]?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

It may not be what you're aiming for, but have you considered xmltodict?
This would let you navigate to the element using a dict which could be easier, if you just need the value of the element and nothing too xml specific.

What did you mean by

it finds the elements, however without the internal elements

?
You have Element. And you can extract keys/values and text, it's children and so on
Also you can use xpath to get all Data tags:
root.xpath('/History/Env/EnvD/Data')

